ECS Service Registers New Target Group with Unhealthy Health Checks (500) During Jenkins Deployment
I'm currently using Jenkins to automate the deployment of a Docker container to an ECS service. When I run the Jenkins pipeline, it registers a new ECS task, but I encounter an issue where a new target group is registered, and the health checks for the new target group fail with 500 error codes.
Here’s what happens step-by-step:
Jenkins builds and pushes a new Docker image to ECR.
Jenkins registers a new ECS task definition and updates the ECS service to use the new task definition.
A new target group is created, and the ECS service attempts to route traffic to the new task.
After a few minutes, the new target group’s health checks fail with 500 status codes, and the task is marked unhealthy.
However, if I manually stop the old task (from the previous deployment) and let the new task run, the health checks pass, and everything works fine.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Increasing the startPeriod in the ECS task health check to give the new task more time to start up.
Checking the logs, which show the application is failing with 500 errors on the health check endpoint.
Questions:
Why does registering a new task in Jenkins result in a new target group, and why do health checks fail in the new target group?
Why does stopping the old task allow the new task to run without issues?
Is there a way to ensure that Jenkins deployment updates the existing target group without creating a new one, or how can I prevent the new target group from failing?
Here’s a summary of my ECS and Jenkins setup:
ECS Cluster: EC2-based.
Jenkins: Automates Docker builds, pushes to ECR, and updates ECS service with --force-new-deployment.
Load Balancer: Application Load Balancer (ALB) used for routing traffic.
Health Check Endpoint: /health returns 500 on new target group but works fine after stopping the old task.
Any help in understanding this behavior and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated!
